# reverse xdelta patch

Tags: patch

Is there way to make reversing xdelta patch?
For example:
A - version 1 of file.
B - version 2 of file.
P - patch.
File B we can renew by appliing patch P to file A.
Is there way to renew file A if I have file B and patch P ?

Answer (score 3):

It's a requested feature, but currently you have to generate two patches:

```
xdelta3 -e -s A B P1
xdelta3 -e -s B A P2
```

Comment: Here is the issue: https://github.com/jmacd/xdelta/issues/62 , feel free to comment if you would like to see it implemented.